# Lightweight Cryptography and Gate Equivalents

Tags: symmetric, cryptographic-hardware, lightweight

If I design a lightweight cryptographic algorithm, how do I calculate gate equivalents (GE)?

Comment: "*If I design a lightweight algorithm*" - If you do this, **please don't use it in a production setting or to actually protect sensitive information**. For an algorithm to be called "lightweight" it typically needs to have fewer gates than the current standard for that platform (AES?)

Comment: Thank you for your advice.
And how do I calculate gates used in the algorithm ?

Comment: I'm not an expert on embedded / integrated circuits (and such stuff), but I'd guess you calculate the number of gates per round and multiply this with the number of rounds. And you get the number required for your round by examing each operation and finding out the required number of gates.

Comment: Please refer the link.
Security for 1000 Gate Equivalents
http://lightweightcrypto.org/present/present_cardis2008.pdf

Comment: In short, a GE is the area of a 2-input NAND gate. For other gates, you use the relative area.